# FSTENV? Can barely find any info about this instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I've got this instruction in a program:

```
FSTENV (28-BYTE) PTR SS:[ESP-1C]
```

What does it do?

Which registers does it use and updates?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that you have googled, what didn't you understand in the tons of documentation results?

Comment: Or is it the operand syntax you don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jerry Coffins Answer is correct.
In case you are wondering about the `(28-BYTE) PTR SS:[ESP-1C]`:
This is the effective address where the FP environment is to be stored, it designates the 28-byte version of the the command and points to 28 (0x1c) bytes below the stack pointer in the stack segment.
I just add the official description from Intel, which I found using a search engine.

> **Description**
>
> Saves the current FPU operating environment at the memory location
>   specified with the destination operand, and then masks all
>   floating-point exceptions. The FPU operating environment consists of
>   the FPU control word, status word, tag word, instruction pointer, data
>   pointer, and last opcode. Figures 7-13 through 7-16 in the IA-32
>   Intel® Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1, show the
>   layout in memory of the stored environment, depending on the operating
>   mode of the processor (protected or real) and the current operand-size
>   attribute (16-bit or 32-bit). In virtual-8086 mode, the real mode
>   layouts are used.
>
> The FSTENV instruction checks for and handles any pending unmasked
>   floating-point exceptions before storing the FPU environment; the
>   FNSTENV instruction does not. The saved image reflects the state of
>   the FPU after all floating-point instructions preceding the
>   FSTENV/FNSTENV instruction in the instruction stream have been
>   executed.
>
> These instructions are often used by exception handlers because they
>   provide access to the FPU instruction and data pointers. The
>   environment is typically saved in the stack. Masking all exceptions
>   after saving the environment prevents floating-point exceptions from
>   interrupting the exception handler. Intel® Architecture Compatibility
>
> When operating a Pentium® or Intel486™ processor in MS-DOS* operating
>   system compatibility mode, it is possible (under unusual
>   circumstances) for an FNSTENV instruction to be interrupted prior to
>   being executed to handle a pending FPU exception. See the section
>   titled "No-Wait FPU Instructions Can Get FPU Interrupt in Window" in
>   Appendix D of the IA-32 Intel® Architecture Software Developer's
>   Manual, Volume 1, for a description of these circumstances. An FNSTENV
>   instruction cannot be interrupted in this way on a Pentium Pro
>   processor.
>
> **Operation**
>
> DEST[FPUControlWord) <- FPUControlWord;
>
> DEST[FPUStatusWord) <- FPUStatusWord;
>
> DEST[FPUTagWord) <- FPUTagWord;
>
> DEST[FPUDataPointer) <- FPUDataPointer;
>
> DEST[FPUInstructionPointer) <- FPUInstructionPointer;
>
> DEST[FPULastInstructionOpcode) <- FPULastInstructionOpcode;
>
> **FPU Flags Affected**
>
> The C0, C1, C2, and C3 are undefined.
>
> **Floating-Point Exceptions**
>
> None.
>
> **Protected Mode Exceptions**
>
> GP(0) - If the destination is located in a nonwritable segment. If a memory operand effective address is outside the CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS
>   segment limit. If the DS, ES, FS, or GS register is used to access
>   memory and it contains a null segment selector.
>
> SS(0) - If a memory operand effective address is outside the SS segment limit.
>
> NM - EM or TS in CR0 is set.
>
> PF(fault-code) - If a page fault occurs.
>
> AC(0) - If alignment checking is enabled and an unaligned memory reference is made while the current privilege level is 3. Real-Address
>   Mode Exceptions
>
> GP - If a memory operand effective address is outside the CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS segment limit.
>
> SS - If a memory operand effective address is outside the SS segment limit.
>
> NM - EM or TS in CR0 is set. Virtual-8086 Mode Exceptions
>
> GP(0) - If a memory operand effective address is outside the CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS segment limit.
>
> SS(0) - If a memory operand effective address is outside the SS segment limit.
>
> NM - EM or TS in CR0 is set.
>
> PF(fault-code) - If a page fault occurs.
>
> AC(0) - If alignment checking is enabled and an unaligned memory reference is made.

Answer (score 8):

Just for the sake of completeness, here's the memory layout that `FSTENV`/`FNSTENV` instructions produce. It is the same in x86-64 `"Long 64-bit Mode"`, and in x86 `"32 bit compatibility mode"` (unless you prepend it with the prefix `66h` in x86-64.)

Quoting [this unwieldy](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) Intel document, this is the layout:

[image]

*(Btw, the image above should've been named "long mode" as well.)*

So if we run an actual test in a long 64-bit mode:

[image]

and break right after `FNSTENV` instruction with the following context state:

[image]

the layout of memory it returns is as follows:

[image]

Which, I'm not gonna hide, is very bizarre. (Anything from a chopped off RIP register to strange looking opcode.) But it is still supported, for legacy reasons, I guess.

The good news is that there are not many uses left today for these archaic x87 FPU instructions when coding the modern x64 code. In that case you should definitely stick with the `XMM0` through `XMM15` registers and their relevant instructions for your floating point needs.

Answer (score 4):

It stores the floating point environment. That includes: the current control word, status word, tag word, instruction pointer, and operand pointer. Those are stored into a structure in memory. In 16-bit mode, that structure is 14 bytes. In 32-bit mode, it's 28 bytes. I'm not at all sure it's available in 64-bit mode (64-bit mode mostly uses SSE instead) [Edit: apparently operates the same in 32-bit and 64-bit mode.]

I don't believe it changes any of the current state of the coprocessor [Edit: oops -- it does, it masks FP exceptions, but most people never unmask them to start with, so...] -- but when you use `fldenv`, that will restore the state to what it was when you used `fstenv` to store it.

Comment: It behaves identically in 64-bit mode and 32-bit mode, and it *does* change the state of the processor: it stores the FPU environment, *then masks all floating-point exceptions*.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Ah, I'd forgotten that -- not a big surprise given the (tiny) number of times I've unmasked FP exceptions to start with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *everybody* forgets that =)

Answer (score 3):

I want to answer the question with different approach.

FSTENV is not "real" instruction.
You may be more lucky when searching for "FNSTENV" opcode.

Look into the encoding closely (from [Intel SDM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)):

```
FSTENV   9B D9 /6  
FNSTENV  D9 /6
```

See that leading "9B"?
It's really a "FWAIT" prepended to "FNSTENV".

So, "FSTENV" is, like many other instructions, is just a convention that is understood by most assemblers and disassemblers.

Intel manual does mention this peculiarity, but you should not expect it to be precise in 100% of cases, sometimes it may omit such details:

> FSTENV/FNSTENV—Store x87 FPU Environment (Vol. 2A 3-393)
>
> The assembler issues **two instructions** for the FSTENV instruction (an **FWAIT** instruction **followed by an FNSTENV**
> instruction), and the processor executes each of these instructions separately. If an exception is generated for
> either of these instructions, the save EIP points to the instruction that caused the exception.

There are many such "special" instructions.
For example, you may be surprised how [much NOP's there are in x86](https://gist.github.com/Quasilyte/b60c94b9cb608d5b1a359d54f1be8aca),
they usually alias other instructions.

### Bonus - useful resources

[Intel XED](https://github.com/intelxed/xed) can be handy in your struggles for several reasons:

1. It can be used as encoder/decoder to validate other tools.
2. It's [datafiles](https://github.com/intelxed/xed/tree/master/datafiles) are a good source of human (and machine) readable ISA info. You may find [engineering notes](https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/master/misc/engineering-notes.txt) that explain datafiles structure.

[Go asm](https://github.com/golang/arch/tree/master/x86) has a thing called [x86.csv](https://github.com/golang/arch/blob/master/x86/x86.v0.2.csv) that lists x86 instructions
in Intel SDM fashion, but sometimes with additional info.
If you grep it for "FSTENV", you will see "pseudo" tag associated with it.
Note that x86.v0.2.csv may miss some instructions, especially from newer extensions (this will be fixed in v0.3 though).